# Setting the background of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to set the background of a JComboBox. I have a form in a JPanel with several JTextFields, JTextAreas and JComboBoxes. For every component I use in my program, the .setBackground is usually fine, except for the JComboBoxes.

Even when I say `comboBox.setBackground(new Color(210, 210, 210))`, the background stays the same as you can see here:

[image]

It's basically just a little detail, but the color of the corners simply doesn't change. I want to change the color of this corners. When using JButtons, the .setBackground()-method is fine as well. Why is it only for JComboBoxes different and what is the right method?

**Solution**

I finally figured out how to change this 'background'. It's actually part of the border. Thus, changing the border(color) fixed that for me.

Comment: This kind of thing should really be done via the Look and Feel (a custom one if need be).

Comment: You would post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

See here how to do it - [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.magenta));
```

Comment: there are two kinds of JComboBox editable and non_editable, this idea doesn't works for Nimbus L&F directly

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't change anything... at least not the color of those corners I mentioned, which are the actual background-color of the combobox.